# Passing data from PFQueryForTableViewController cell through segue to viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform

so I am trying to pass data from my cell (populated with `queryForTable` method) through a segue to another `viewController`. I am using the `prepareForSegue` method and my code looks like:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"profile"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
        ProfileViewController *userProfile = [segue destinationViewController]; //(ProfileViewController *) nav.topViewController;
        userProfile.userInfo = object;
    }
}
```

in my VC I have the property defined:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) PFObject *userInfo;
```

but when I run my code I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setUserInfo:]:
```

Comment: Did you subclass the view controller in your storyboard to `ProfileViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the viewController you're pulling out of the segue isn't a `ProfileViewController` - the error you're getting states:

```
-[UIViewController setUserInfo:]:
```

Note `UIViewController`, not `ProfileViewController`. This would seem to indicate that your segue's destination viewController isn't exactly what you think it is.

Check your destination viewController's class in your Storyboard. Is it set to `ProfileViewController`? Is your `ProfileViewController` embedded inside another viewController (like a navigationController - looking at your commented out code, you seem to have treated it as such before)? If so, you might need to do a big more digging to get a reference to the correct viewController.

Comment: Soooo.... I'm going to feel really stupid right now, but I didn't have my class set up to my storyboard.. But thanks a ton I really appreciate the help!